# Current state of zero knowledge proofs?

Tags: blockchain, privacy, encryption, zero-knowledge

Are there any current proof of concepts or implementations of zero knowledge proofs in the context of smart contracts?

If not how long until we can store private data on a public blockchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ropsten testnet has just verified a tranasction from the zCash network via a zkSNARK. For more details, have a look at the zkSNARK code, available [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa1f11d83a5222692c0eff9eca32254a7452c4f29).